# Kubernetes service not creating endpoint despite selector

Tags: kubernetes

I am sure I am missing something clear as day, but here goes. I have a frontend and backend being deployed behind an Nginx ingress. The requests to the backend were timing out, so I tested with a `curl` pod. I found that I was able to hit the pods directly, but not the service. This led me to run:

```sh
> kubectl get endpoints

NAME                                               ENDPOINTS                        AGE
backend-api                                        <none>                           10m
kubernetes                                         167.99.101.163:443               121d
nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller             10.244.0.17:80,10.244.0.17:443   96m
nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller-admission   10.244.0.17:8443                 96m
vue-frontend                                       10.244.0.24:80                   84m
```

No endpoints... I recall (from when I initially set this deployment up) that this usually has to do with selectors. I have checked and checked and checked, but I swear I have it set up correctly. Clearly not though.

```yaml
## api-deployment.yaml
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backend-api
  labels:
    app: backend-api
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: backend-api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: backend-api
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: backend-api
        image: us.gcr.io/container-registry-276104/backend-api:0.88
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        env:
        ...
```

```sh
> kubectl get pods --show-labels
NAME                                                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   LABELS
backend-api-76d6d4f4c9-drbmn                              1/1     Running   0          85m   app=backend-api,pod-template-hash=76d6d4f4c9
backend-api-76d6d4f4c9-qpbhk                              1/1     Running   0          85m   app=backend-api,pod-template-hash=76d6d4f4c9
curl-curlpod-7b46d7776f-jkt6f                             1/1     Running   0          47m   pod-template-hash=7b46d7776f,run=curl-curlpod
nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller-5475c95bbf-psmzr   1/1     Running   0          97m   app.kubernetes.io/component=controller,app.kubernetes.io/instance=nginx-ingress,app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx,pod-template-hash=5475c95bbf
vue-frontend-6dbf68446f-pzv5h                             1/1     Running   0          85m   app=vue-frontend,pod-template-hash=6dbf68446f
```

and the service:

```yaml
## api-service.yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: backend-api
spec:
  selector:
    app: backend-api
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http
  publishNotReadyAddresses: true
```

Help is, of course, appreciated :) I normally beat my head against the wall for hours, but I'm learning to work smarter, not harder!

Happy to answer any questions - thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you got the service ports mixed up. `targetPort` is set to `http`, which is port 80. This is the port that the service forwards to on the pod. The `port` value of the service is the port service exposes. So if you want your service to forward traffic to port 8080 of your pod, set `targetPort` to 8080.

Answer (score 0):

```yaml
  ports:
  - port: ***
    targetPort: ***
```

In Service the `port` defines in which port, you finally want to expose your app.
`targetPort` is the one where you exposed your pod.

So, the `targetPort` in your `Service` should be same as `containerPort` in your `Pod`.